# Do I use GCloud Cloud DNS Nameservers on Hostgator Domain, or the other way around?

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I want to use a domain I bought through Hostgator with my Google Cloud Platform project.

Do I use the hostgator nameservers on Google Cloud DNS or the other way around?

Thanks,

Comment: When you say "Gcloud project", do you mean an AppEngine project? If so, simply follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl?hl=en).

Comment: you could create the zone records in cloud dns for the Hostgator domain and the nameservers you receive for zone, should be configured in Hostgator as the nameserver

Comment: Why -1?  It's a valid question.  Answer was here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-dns?hl=en

Comment: This is a genuine/valid question, which I was also looking forward to reading a real answer... Evidently, nobody appears to have understood it (the question wasn't a "how-to", but rather a "which-one" question...). The link provided in the accepted answer is great in explaining the two optional approaches, but it doesn't recommend one over the other, which I think is what the OP was trying to decide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Gcloud compute engine, help on DNS configuration for custom domains can be found here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-dns?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use the Name Servers that has been generated automatically from Cloud DNS and edit your Domain Registrar Name servers. It should be similar.